# Code not working when using models and views - Backbone

Tags: javascript

I have tried following code and still it isn't working:

```
alert = Backbone.model.extend({

initialize: function()
{
    alert("hello world");
}

});

$(document).ready(function(){

   var alert=new alert();
});
```

Comment: You had redefined native `alert` function and now it calls itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call your model *alert* and it will work